# jqPlot Bar Chart not displayed in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, jqplot

I am trying to display bar chart using jqPlot bar chart. I have doing code which display chart in Internet Explorer. But for same code chart does not displayed in Crome and Mozilla browser.
I  have given the code below-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<style>
<title>Home</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js">           </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jQuery/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jQuery/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jQuery/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jQuery/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jQuery/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js">   </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/jQuery/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

<script>
function drawChart() {
alert("In draw chart");
  var s1 = [2, 6, 7];
  var s2 = [7, 5, 3];
  var s3 = [2, 3, 5];
  var s4 = [1, 7, 2];

  // chart data
  var dataArray = [s1, s2, s3, s4];

  // x-axis ticks
  var ticks = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'];

  // chart rendering options
  var options = {
    seriesDefaults: {
      renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: ticks
      }
    }
  };

  // draw the chart
  $.jqplot('showData', dataArray, options);
}// end
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button value="Get Employee Data" onclick="drawChart()">Get Chart</button>
<div id="showData" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Why this code does not work for Crome and Mozilla browser?

Comment: Have you checked the consoles of those browsers for errors?

Comment: Yes, there is no any error

Comment: In `var dataArray = [s1, s2, s3, 24];`, isn't that supposed to be an s4, not 24?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the graph displaying in IE9, FF and Chrome by:

1. Removing the  `<style>` tag. This tag prevented anything displaying in all browsers.
2. Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the file. This prevented an error in IE9.

Also, the way you are linking to `json2.js` is actually retrieving the Github page that displays the file, not the actual file itself.

Comment: @virajdhamal What sort of error message are you getting? You will probably need to use the developer tools in the respective browsers to track down the error.

Comment: I am getting error like: Unable to get value of the property 'BarRenderer': object is null or undefined

Comment: @virajdhamal Are you getting that error across all browsers? If so, then it would pay to check that the file `jqplot.barRenderer.min.js` actually exists in `resources/jQuery/plugins/`.

Comment: I have removed ../ from <script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/....."></script> and now code works for IE,FF and crome well